# Parallel code not working when function to parallelize is in a different file

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a simple function that I want to run in parallel. If the function is directly specified in the main function, it all works nicely. But if the very same function is called from a separate Python file (that is created to contains a series of helper functions), the code fails with the error:

**A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.**

I have tried to run this code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import otherFile as of

inputs = range(10) 
def processInput(i):
    return i * i

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

results1 = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(processInput)(i) for i in inputs) # this works
results2 = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(of.processInput)(i) for i in inputs) # this fails
```

When I call the function processInput() from the of file I have simply copied the same function in that .py file.

```
def processInput(i):
    return i * i
```

How can I make the parallelization work if the function I need to call is in a separate .py file?

This is the full error:

```
results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(of.processInput)(i) for i in inputs)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-387-d8dd1dc361a6>", line 1, in <module>
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(of.processInput)(i) for i in inputs)

  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 934, in __call__
    self.retrieve()

  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))

  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)

  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()

  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception

BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.*
```

Comment: Can you please post the error stack as well

Comment: what does the code in the of file look like?  does the full program produce any output?  what does that output look like?

Comment: I added the required details

Comment: I tried running your example but it runs fine on my setup.

Comment: Have you tried with calling the function processInput(i) from a different py file as well?

Comment: SHORT: try putting `num_cores =` and following code under `if __name__ == "__main__":`. LONGER: Works fine under linux. I think that on windows subprocess does not inherit "parent resources", so it has to pickle all the objects in the module, which includes instances of `Parallel` that are not picklable, and so  `of.processInput` becomes non-picklable too

Comment: My previous assumption about recursive subprocesses spawning under windows is even mentioned in the docs: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#old-multiprocessing-backend . Also it might not work if you simply pasting this code to interactive shell... I'd recommend you to also read this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods

Comment: Never a function works parallel, other point is "you can't reach to resource if its run in another thread",  issue:some time work, function is frozen, can't restart again etc...

Comment: @opt Yes. The only difference between my setup and yours I think is in the name of the files ( and of the functions ), which should not matter. What version are you using? use `pip show joblib` to assure you have the latest version, it is reporting `0.13.2` to me.

Comment: @bracco23 I have version 0.13.2 as well

Comment: @opt https://repl.it/repls/AfraidGiddyDiscussion here an executable version. It gives no problem on the online compiler, and the same happens on my machine. Python version? `python -V` on my machine says `3.4.1`

Comment: My Python version is 3.7.1, not sure if this is what causing the issue?

Comment: @opt I wonder whether it's a ipython issue. I ran your program and I tried different way of importing and even changing the function on the file to see different results from the two functions on Windows 10 Pro Python 3.7.0 64 bit version (Anaconda) and it works fine from a PyCharm Run console. Can you try running outside of ipython and see?

Comment: do you work with sklearn ?

Comment: works like a charm on my machine with python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3 and 3.6.1. The python version may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have checked if the imported function 'of.processInput' works without using multiprocessing? If it doesn't work, then this could be the elephant in the room that others have not pointed out. Maybe you're missing

```
__init__.py
```

or maybe it is because the directory is not being seen by Python's `import` command. To add the directory you can do:

```
import sys; sys.path.append("path/to/otherFile/")
```

Though I am not sure if the error message you get is even remotely related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

just import the function like this

```
from otherFile import processinput
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same error "A task has failed to un-serialize"